# Как перенести кастомные шрифты в Scene Builder

Tags: java, javafx, scene-builder

Как перенести кастомные шрифты, которые я ставлю в Scene Builder, имеющиеся на ПК, но при переходе и запуске в Intellej не работает. При запуске, шрифты не те,, которые в Scene Builder

Пробовал css, но не вышло,, может не правильно адаптировал

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.